# Compress toDataURL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, compression, todataurl

You could compress output using Javascript?

> canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg',quality);

Maybe by compressing the string itself toDataURL?

In this example: http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/ to include a data format of the output image toDataURL, gives the following result compress:

> Compressed
> From 4645 (4.54 Kb) to: 3980 (3.89 Kb)
>
> Conversion
> +Completed in 1.1181 seconds from 3980 (3.89 Kb) to: 5308 (5.18 Kb)
>
> Type: image / jpeg
> Height: 240px
> Width: 320px

Comment: Are you telling us we can do this, or did you have a question ?

Comment: Sorry, it is a question. Rectified the main question.

Comment: You could just decode the base-64 string to get the originally compressed binary data (which would cut the size by 33%)